# Programa C excluir valor do vetor e diminui-lo em uma unidade

Tags: c, array

Pessoal to com um problema seguinte tenho que fazer um programa que implementa uma rotina que le 10 numeros de um vetor e depois recebe um valor a ser pesquisado no vetor caso encontre apaga esse valor e diminui o tamanho do vetor em uma unidade, eu tentei o codigo a seguir por sugestão de um amigo de implementar um vetor secundario para receber o vetor reduzido, mas não ta dando certo, alguem me da um help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int vet[10],vet2[9];
    int val;

    printf("\nDigite os valores do vetor: ");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        scanf("%d",&vet[i]);
    }
    printf("Digite o valor a ser pesquisado e exluido: ");
    scanf("%d",&val);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(val==vet[i]){
            vet[i+1];
        }
        else{
            vet2[i]=vet[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        printf("%d\n", vet2[i]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você usa o i de um for que vai rodar 10 vezes em um vetor que só tem 9 posições, você tem que usar uma variável diferente do i, uma que incremente apenas até o 9.
Poderia ficar assim por exemplo:

```
    for(int i=0,j=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      if(vet[i]!=val)
      {
        vet2[j]=vet[i];
        j++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Olha funcionou certinho, eu tinha esquecido dessa questão dos indices, obrigado.

Comment: De nada. Mas pela lógica que tu implementa, provável de dar algum erro se o vetor tiver valores repetidos e um desses valores repetidos forem excluidos

Comment: Bom, e verdade mais o enunciado não cita repetições